# A Simple automatic completion Editor

Tags: editor

I have a genric BNF grammar and I would like to implement an editor, starting from that grammar and through an automatic completion feature, that can suggest phrases and signle strings belonging to a language derived from that grammar.
What can be the best approach to implement this editor?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest [KDE's "kate"](http://www.kde.org/applications/utilities/kate/) editor:

- mature and flexible editor
- Qt based, so cross platform
- excellent highlighting engine
- working autocompletion engine
- usable standalone or embedded

Using such an existing editor just leaves the task to implement a syntax description and load it into the editor. This approach is much less error prone as starting from scratch trying to implement editor number 29583659.